# Spring: How to programmatically fill a list of bean references in a list property on a BeanDefinition?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In the XML configuration of a Spring application context I can fill a list-property on a bean definition with references to appropriate beans, for example:

```xml
<bean id="company" class="SimpleTestProject.beans.jobs.Company">
  <property name="workers">
    <list>
      <ref bean="worker1"/>
      <ref bean="worker2"/>
      <ref bean="worker3"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Now what I would like to do, is to fill such a property programmatically. Suppose, my `BeanFactory` is processed by a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. And in the `postProcessBeanFactory()` method I find my company `BeanDefinition`, which has a list property. Then I register a list of singleton beans of type `Worker` on this `BeanFactory` by calling `beanFactory.registerSingleton(...)` for each one of them. Now how can I fill the references to those new `BeanDefinition`s into the list on the `company` bean? I have seen, there is a method like

```java
beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("beanName").getPropertyValues().setPropertyValueAt(...)
```

which obviously does set a Bean property. But how I can pass a list of references to it? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have registered the singleton beans to the BeanFactory , you can autowire the same to any Bean as follows

```
@Autowired
List<Worker> workers;
```

Spring Container would automatically provide you the list of beans of matching type to this List reference.

From [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-autowire)

> With byType or constructor autowiring mode, you can wire arrays and
>   typed collections. In such cases, all autowire candidates within the
>   container that match the expected type are provided to satisfy the
>   dependency

If you are trying to avoid `@Autowired` annotation , following from `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` would also work . Assuming you have already added the following field to a bean named *company*

```
List<Worker> workers;
```

within BeanFactoryPostProcessor

```
List<Object> workers = new ArrayList<Object>();
workers.add(beanFactory.getBean("worker1"));
workers.add(beanFactory.getBean("worker2"));

beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("company").getPropertyValues().addPropertyValue("workers",workers);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I know I can use autowire, but the problem is, what if I have multiple companies and I want to fill each one of them with the corresponding workers. Autowire would add all workers to all companies, I guess. Concerning the BeanFactoryPostProcessor code, this is nice, thank you :) But is there a way to wire only bean definitions, without creating the beans yet?

Comment: If workers for a company can fall under one Type , say CompananyOneWorker , it would work. With beanFactory.registerSingleton(...) the beans are already created right ?